# How to make If statements in Databound ListView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a ListView with many advanced controls and html tags. ListView is bound to collection of profiles when first profile in collection is current profile. current profile has few differences from other profiles ie. flash embed, js and some other stuff. I can access inside of my ListView Container.DataIndex property which gives me 0 as first item in index but i'm unable to use inline If statements like so

```
<% If Container.DataIndex = 0 Then %>
do stuff
<% EndIf %>
```

this is because i must place pound to access databound item but neither this

```
<%# If Container.DataIndex = 0 Then %>
do stuff
<% EndIf %>
```

How can i make inline If ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItemIndex")) { %>
  do stuff
<% } else { %>
  do other stuff
<%} %>
```

Here is a small summary of the inline aspx tags:
http://naspinski.net/post/inline-aspnet-tags-sorting-them-all-out-%283c25242c-3c253d2c-3c252c-3c252c-etc%29.aspx

But i would recommend to use [ListView.ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx). It is less error-prone and more readable in codebehind.

Comment: @rdans: Have you used `<%#` or `<%%`, where have you used it? Show the code. Maybe you want to post a question since it's diffcult to help in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean [IIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27ydhh0d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? IIF - Returns one of two objects, depending on the evaluation of an expression.